# Check if sheet name exists, if true increment number in sheet name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following section of code:

```
  var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  var existingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(date);
  if (existingSheet) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(date + "[OLD]");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(date);
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(date);
  }
```

However, I know this will fail when/if it is called for a 3rd time on the same date as a sheet with the the name will already exist (I don't want to delete the first created sheet with the *date [OLD]* name format).

What would be the best way to add a incrementing number to the sheet name?
When the script runs, it checks if the sheet exists, if it does it renames the sheet to *date [OLD]* - the next time it runs it it would rename the last created sheet to *date [OLD 2]* and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding a flush() after each call to apply the pending updates to the sheet before adding a new sheet.

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Comment: Hey Amit. The code is part of a larger piece of code called from a UI menu.
Basically, it creates a new sheet using the `var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()` as a name. So for today, it will produce *24 October 2018*. If they run the script from the menu again, it renames *24 October 2018* to *24 October 2018 [OLD]* and then inserts a new sheet called *24 October 2018*. The problem being if they run it again, it will fail as *24 October 2018 [OLD]* already exists (so it can't rename the most recent *24 October 2018* to *24 October 2018 [OLD]*).

Comment: Expaning on this - it will produce the error message: `A sheet with the name ‘24 October 2018 [OLD]’ already exists. Please enter another name.`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a similar but more generic function that appends "_1" to the name of an existing sheet and increments the number as needed.

Note that in the main code I also illustrate how to use insertSheet to insert a new sheet with a copy of the data from the original sheet, as well as how to insert the copy as the last sheet, rather than as the first sheet, in the spreadsheet document.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object)

```
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  origSheetName = "March 2021";
  var origSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(origSheetName);

  //returns original, or _1, _2 ... when a sheet by a prior name exists
  var name = getFirstUnusedName(sourceSS, origSheetName);

  //Note: using the option {template: origSheet} copies the data to the new sheet
  //Note 2: adding the index of 199 places the sheet with the appended _number
  //as the last instead of as the first sheet (maximum 200 sheets in a workbook)

  sourceSS.insertSheet(name, 199, {template: origSheet}); 
  

//note that this function yields SheetName, SheetName_1 ... 
//instead of SheetName, SheetName [OLD], SheetName [OLD 2] ... 

function getFirstUnusedName(sourceSS, name) {
  var existingSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
  if (!existingSheet) {
    return name;
  } else {
    name =  name + "_1";
    existingSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
    //if already appended _1, loop to find lowest unused number
    while (existingSheet) {
          nameNum = parseInt( name.split('_').pop() ) + 1;
          //the following line does assume there is only one '_' in the sheetname
          //if necessary change the split character(s) to be unique, 
          //or use a regex lookahead instead
          name = name.split('_')[0].toString() + "_" + nameNum.toString();   
          existingSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
    }
    return name;
  }
}
```

This question is old, and the more generic function & explanation will probably help more people. However, if the exact sequence of [OLD], [OLD 2], [OLD ]... is still desired, that function follows. It requires an additional conditional.

Note that the main code calling it differs as well. This main renames any existing sheet and inserts a new blank sheet named by the date as the first sheet in the document.

```
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  var existingSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(date);

  //if sheet [date] exists, rename it; make a new sheet named [date]
  var name = getFirstUnusedNameInOldFormat(sourceSS, date);
  if (name != date) { sourceSS.renameActiveSheet(name); }
  sourceSS.insertSheet(date);


function getFirstUnusedNameInOldFormat(sourceSS, name) {
  var existingSpreadsheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
  if (!existingSpreadsheet) {
    return name;
  } else {
    name = name + " [OLD]"; //the initial [OLD] instead of _1 or [OLD 1] requires an additional conditional
    existingSpreadsheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
    if (!existingSpreadsheet) {
      return name;
    } else {
      name = name.split(" [OLD]")[0] + " [OLD 2]"; //note desired behavior is to skip appending [OLD 1]
      existingSpreadsheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
      while (existingSpreadsheet) {
        nameNum = parseInt( name.split(" [OLD ").pop().slice(0,-1) ) + 1;
        name = name.split(" [OLD ")[0].toString() + " [OLD " + nameNum.toString() + "]";   
        existingSpreadsheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(name);
      }
      return name;
    }
  }
}
```